# How to Pause C# code execution without blocking main thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, animation, wait

OK so we have a program where we want to animate the controls on a WinForm and then then resume subsequent operations of the remaining block of code. Here is the sample code.

The function is on the WinForm, which is running on main thread presumably

```
 Private void DoThisWork();
    {

    do some work here

    animateControls()
    //<NEED TO PAUSE HERE WHILE THE GUI ANIMATES AND UPDATES DISPLAYING THE ANIMATION OF THE CONTROL>

    //Tried Option 1: thread.sleep. When we do this the main thread blocks and the animation is //not seen. The control is directly painted at x1,y1 and thats it, the intermediate rendering is not seen

    // Tried Option 2: Application.DoEvents. This works very well except that the CPU maxes out and the animation then appears very jittery

   continue doing remaining work  // must execute only after animateControls() completes the animation part.

}
```

Now, `animateControls()` is simply a function that is on a timer and moves a control from point (x,y) to (x1,y1) and this takes about 3 seconds.

SuspendLayout and ResumeLayout dont force GUI update because thread.sleep caused the main thread to block so everything is virtually at a standstill.

Using a different thread to animate the GUI does not seem to help because I still need for the entire animation to complete.

Also, I cannot add anything in the animation code because it is called from multiple functions and therefore is used as a common function.

Answer (score 3):

Your are going down the wrong path. Put your work to do on a seperate thread and let your UI Thread do your animation till the work thread is finished.

The BackgroundWorker class might come in handy. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Comment: Actually  DoThisWork() is a very large function with many switch cases. The animation comes into play only in a couple of these cases. I cannot put DoThisWork() on a worker thread. The main problem is DoEvents. When multiple forms are opened, DoEvents will only animate one form at a time!

Comment: Maybe you can restructure DoThisWork() into separate methods. Once a long running operation has to be done let this work on another thread. Meanwhile animate your window with UI Thread. From the information provided i believe other solutions will only be workarounds and are hard to discuss without having the full code available. Rethink the overall approach - running some long running operation on the UI Thread and calling some animation code via events will be hard to get working as described.

Comment: Yes, that's the last recourse, but I am hoping to avoid that! :)

Comment: Thomas I am working on the lines suggested by you and I am getting some results. Lets see how it goes and I will get back with something

Comment: OK that did not work. After some serious juggling around, the GUI still remains rather jittery and animations are locking up too much. I guess there is no solution to this.